# Return exact result from Async function F#

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, f#

So, here is C# code and I`d like to do something like this in F#:

```
class Main 
{
    private Task<bool> A()
    {
        return Task<bool>.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

I haven`t seen anything similar in MS docs. Any ideas how can i do this?..

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no equivalent of FromResult for Async.

Assuming you want it to return Async rather than Task then you can use this:

```
let A () = async { return true }
```

If you want it to return Task then just use the same function as the C# code:

```
let A () = Task.FromResult true
```

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer mentions, you can create an async compuatation expression that returns true. However, this just compiles down to:

```ml
let A () = async.Return(true)
```

So you can simplify a bit and use that instead if you prefer. It looks more like the original C# as well.